# tomcat to print angular http client logs

Tags: angular, tomcat, tomcat8

I have some tomcat based application, and angular based java script to fetch some content from application  server and show it in UI, so I have like below

**UI(broswers)->tomcat Host server ->application serevr**

now I need to print all http request made my angular at tomcat logs with client IP, I did below changes to tomcat config file

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" />
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
              pattern="combined" resolveHosts="false"/>
```

Log I am getting is

```
10.2.107.13 - - [29/Apr/2020:15:34:16 +0530] "GET /egway/fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505a9eed503f8b8.woff2?v=4.7.0 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://10.2.8.4:8080/egway/styles.adcc05581e8dbd8e6115.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"
```

But I am not getting the logs made by angular http code, so I tried to check my application logs but there problem is I always gets the client IP as tomcat server host  IP.

Also added this filter in web.xml but still I am not getting request logs at tomcat

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>requestdumper</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestdumper</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

So is it possible have any of these

1. Print tomcat logs with my angular http request logs
2. Make tomcat to forward the client IP(browser IP) as x-forwarder ip to my application server

The tomcat version I am using is **8.5.51**